# ANSI C do you have to use malloc() when creating a struct?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc

Let's say I have this `struct` in ANSI C:

```
typedef struct _point
{
    float x;
    float y;
} Point;
```

and this function to create this `struct`:

```
Point createpoint(float x, float y)
{
    Point p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    return p; 
}
```

This allows me to create a `struct` with this function i.e:

```
int main()
{
    Point pointOne = createpoint(5, 6);  
    Point pointTwo = createpoint(10, 4);
    float distance = calculatedistancefunc(pointOne, pointTwo);

    /* ...other stuff */

    return 0;
}
```

Someone told me that this code is not valid, because the `struct` does not get `malloc`'d in the `createpoint(float x, float y)` function before it gets returned, and that the `struct` will be deleted. 
However, when I use my `struct` like this, it doesn't seem to get deleted.

So my question is:
do I have to `malloc` this `struct`, and why? / why not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whatever you are doing is entirely correct. The statement -

```
return p;
```

in the function returns a **copy** of the local variable `p`. But if you want the same object that was created in the function, then you need to `malloc` it. However, you need to `free` it later.

```
Point createpoint(float x, float y)
{
    Point p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    return p; 
} // p is no longer valid from this point. So, what you are returning is a copy of it.
```

But -

```
Point* createpoint(float x, float y)
{
    Point *p = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    return p; 
}// Now you return the object that p is pointing to.
```

Comment: Which is IMHO kind of ill advised. If you wish to do memory management right, you should not return with a pointer to a dinamically alocated struct allocated in your function. You should request a preallocated pointer in a third parameter and fill it within your method.

Comment: @mg30rg Why should you pass a pre-alloced struct pointer when you can do it in the function and return it?

Comment: @YassineHoussni - Because you more than likely will read your code more times than you write it, so code readability is more important then coding comfort. If you keep your memory allocaton and release in the same block, it will be harder to leak memory, because resources are only reserved for the exact period they are needed, and every resevation (i.e.: `malloc()`/`getmem()`/`new`) is visually paired with a disallocation (`free()`/`freemem()`/`delete`). You can easily spot a `new` with no `delete`, but will you spot a `createpoint()` without `delete`? And will the maintenance programmer do?

Comment: @mg30rg Yes you're right, that is a very good point, thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can return `struct` on the stack, your code is valid. A problem would occur if you'd to return a pointer to the local variable, but that's not what you're doing, you're returning a copy, that's fine.

Comment: But you should care about memory usage if you follow the same process with a bigger struct, as every field is copied when the return occurs. In that specific case, that should not be an issue anyway.

Comment: @Kernald - there are memory usage concerns, performance concerns, stack depth concerns, but its irrelevant to the OP's direct question. It **is** a valid C code.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answers everybody,

But I can't seem to understand why 'pass by reference' is more memory efficient than 'pass by value'. I mean, both ways store the same amount of data in the struct?

Comment: @Marnixv.R. pass by value essentially copies the value. This is fine with small variables (like integers), but with structs, especially the large ones, creating a copy is wasteful. By reference means you're referencing the existing variable, not copying it into a new one.

Comment: @littleadv: The C model of computation does not contain a stack, and C implementations do not necessarily put function return values on the stack. For functions that return large objects, an implementation may, in its internal details, require callers to pass to the function the address of a place to put the return value, and the function fills it in there rather than on the stack.

Comment: @Kernald: There is not necessarily any copy when the function returns. As noted in my previous comment, a C implementation may implement returns of large objects by passing the function a pointer to a place to put the return value. Then the optimized code for the function may simply work with the object in that location, rather than on the stack or other temporary locations, so the object is already in place when the function returns.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: In cases where the function return is going to be stored in a variable with static or global scope, or in a variable whose address is taken, I think either the caller would have to create a temp, pass the address of that, and copy the data from that to its new home, or else the calling convention would have to require that the called function not write to the received pointer until after any and all code which might examine things of static or global scope, or dereference any non-restricted pointers, has run [and that restriction could result in copying].

Comment: @supercat: No, none of that is necessary in general. It is necessary that the caller provide space that is not otherwise in use (e.g., not space the called routine might access, directly or indirectly, if it obeys the aliasing rules). So, if the called routine does `t = foo(…)` and `t` is an automatic object and has not had its address taken, then the caller can simply pass the address of `t`. If the address of `t` has been taken but none of the parameters are allowed to alias it, the address of `t` can still be passed. Furthermore, if `t` cannot be passed, the calling routine can make…

Comment: … temporary space, pass the address of that, and then use the object directly from there, rather than copying it into `t`. Even if the calling code later has references in it like `t.a`, the C standard does not require the implementation to actually copy the data into `t` and then access `t.a`. It merely requires the same result, which optimization can achieve by fetching `t.a` from the temporary space.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If the calling convention specifies that the caller is forbidden from passing a reference that might alias anything visible by the called method, then the generated code for the called function may store things directly into the return-value buffer. If the calling convention instead specifies that the called function must not write to the received reference until after the last access to anything which could alias it, then a caller could elide the copy operation when assigning to something that could be aliased. Each convention would be better in some cases; worse in others.

Answer (score 5):

C99 allows for even nicer on-the-stack creation of structs.
Given the below struct

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
} Point;
```

you can initialize it in a bit of a C++ constructor style manner with the following statement:

```
Point p = (Point){0.4, 0.5};
```

and thus you could either shorten your createpoint or scrap it altogether:

```
int main()
{
    Point pointOne = (Point){5, 6};
    Point pointTwo = (Point){10, 4};
    float distance = calculatedistancefunc(pointOne, pointTwo);
    //...other stuff
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Point createpoint(float x, float y)
{
    Point p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    return p; 
} /
```

All local variables in function are deleted `after` function returns.

1> **pass by reference** 
So if you are returning pointer to this local variable then after function return this variables are deleted so that pointers are invalid.

2>  **pass by value** 
But here you are returning copy of this local variable so its safe because that local variable are gona dead when function returns but the copy of return value will be stored in receiver variable in function call before function return.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, however I have a new question now.

When should you prefer passing by refference and when should you prefere pass by value?

Comment: when you are going to malloc something in local function then pass it by refference & when you are returning something local variable pass it by value.. more you can google it..!!!

Comment: you can ask another question for that also...!

Answer (score 0):

A call to a method which returns a structure will behave as though the caller creates a temporary variable of the structure type somewhere which isn't visible in any other scope, and gives the called function a pointer to it.  The called function will then put the data in the requested place, and after it returns the caller will be able to read the data from its new variable.  Given a function and calling code:

```
StructType BuildStruct(void)
{
  StructType it;
  it.this=4;
  it.that=23;
  return it;
}

StructType myStruct;
myStruct = BuildStruct();
```

it's likely that there will be at least one copy operation if not two; the statement `return it;` may need to copy from local variable `it` to the temporary struct, and the assignment to `myStruct` may need to copy from the temporary location to `myStruct`.  No situation actually requires two copy operations; some require one (which could be performed by the caller or by the called method) and some require none, but the necessity of copying is dependent upon details in both the caller and the called method.

An alternative design would be:

```
void BuildStruct(StructType *it)
{
  it->this=4;
  it->that=23;
}

StructType myStruct;
BuildStruct(&myStruct);
```

That would likely yield code equivalent to the best code one could hope for using a structure-type return variable, since the struct data would be placed directly into its final spot without any structure copying being necessary.